# Angular checkbox values

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-material

I have trouble with setting the `checkbox` values in a form. The problem i can't solve is that when i want to update a form and I get the data for it all the `checkboxes` return true every time and shown as checked even when the `checkboxes` are false(unchecked).

here is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpClientService, Employee } from '../service/http-client.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-employee',
  templateUrl: './edit-employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-employee.component.css']
})
export class EditEmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

  user: Employee;
  editForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private httpClientService: HttpClientService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let userId = window.localStorage.getItem("editEmployeeId");
    if (!userId) {
      alert("Invalid action.")
      this.router.navigate(['employee']);
      return;
    }
    this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      enabled: [''],
      admin: [''],
      supervisor: ['']
    });

    this.editForm.setErrors({ required: true });
    this.editForm.valueChanges.subscribe((newValue) => {
      let enabledCheckbox = (newValue.enabled) ? 'Y' : 'N';
      let adminCheckbox = (newValue.admin) ? 'Y' : 'N';
      let supervisorCheckbox = (newValue.supervisor) ? 'Y' : 'N';

      newValue.enabled = enabledCheckbox;
      newValue.admin = adminCheckbox;
      newValue.supervisor = supervisorCheckbox;

      if (newValue.admin === true || newValue.supervisor === true) {
        this.editForm.setErrors(null);
      } else {
        this.editForm.setErrors({ required: true });
      }

    });
    this.httpClientService.getEmployeeById(+userId)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.editForm.patchValue(data);
      });
  }

  onSubmit() {

    this.httpClientService.updateEmployee(this.editForm.value)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
            this.router.navigate(['employee']);
        },
        error => {
          // alert(error);
        });
  }

}
```

and my html:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <h2 class="text-center">Edit user</h2>
  <form [formGroup]="editForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

    <div class="form-group">
      <mat-checkbox formControlName="enabled" class="form-control" color="primary">
        Enabled</mat-checkbox>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <mat-checkbox formControlName="admin" class="form-control" color="primary">
        Admin</mat-checkbox>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <mat-checkbox formControlName="supervisor" class="form-control" color="primary">
        Supervisor</mat-checkbox>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="onSubmit()"
        routerLink="/">Update</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

after I set them for the update everything works and get the right status of the `checkboxes` and saved in the table but if i want to update then they are always shown as checked in the form, any advice why this happens?

Comment: Does all your values are required ? Why not using `Validators.required` ?

Comment: Have you tried initializing your checkbox controls to a boolean value? 
```
    this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      enabled: [false],
      admin: [false],
      supervisor: [false]
    });
```

Comment: yes that wont help it overrides it in the ```newValue``` part and sets it to true automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after several tries I finally managed to make the `checkbox` show the current state they have to.

Here's how I did that:

```
    this.httpClientService.getEmployeeById(+userId)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.user = data;
        this.user.enabled = this.formatCheckboxesToTrueOrFalse(this.user.enabled);
        this.user.admin = this.formatCheckboxesToTrueOrFalse(this.user.admin);
        this.user.supervisor = this.formatCheckboxesToTrueOrFalse(this.user.supervisor);
        this.editForm.patchValue(data);
        console.log(data);
      });
  }

  formatCheckboxesToTrueOrFalse(checkbox) {
    let formattedCheckboxes = null
    switch (checkbox) {
      case 'Y': formattedCheckboxes = true;

        break;
      case 'N': formattedCheckboxes = false;

        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    return formattedCheckboxes;
  }
```

I had to format them as they got the value from the database ('Y' for checked and 'N' for unchecked) and subscribe to that formatted data and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because on every change you set the value of the checkboxes to a non-empty string wich coerces to `true`. You also need to make sure that the data structure of the request you're making fits the form:

```
interface Employee {
    ...
    enabled: boolean;
    admin: boolean;
    supervisor: boolean;
    ...
}
```

In the change subscription your dont't need to set the value at all, the checkboxes toggle and store the value in the `FormGroup` automatically.